# run.font.italic and run.font.bold return None instead of True

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I need to get all text that is italic and bold in paragraphs. I am manually turning text into italic and bold form but the code below returns none. Is it only an initiator or can we get the value out of it as well, how can I get all italic and bold text?

```
def get_italic_ratio(slide):
    count = 0
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        if not shape.has_text_frame:
            continue
        text_frame = shape.text_frame
        par = text_frame.paragraphs[0]
        run = par.add_run()
        print(run.font.italic) # returns None, should return True 
        print(run.font.bold) # returns None, should return True 

        print(text_frame.paragraphs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your question is how to find the "effective" value of a font formatting parameter.

The formatting for a run of text is determined by a set of rules operating on the style hierarchy. If a formatting attribute (say bold) is applied directly to the run, that takes precedence. When bold is not applied directly, run.bold returns None, and the run's "boldness" is determined by checking the rest of the style hierarchy. This could be properties on the slide layout, the slide master or a theme or presentation default (and perhaps other possibilities).

So finding the effective value requires discovering these rules and navigating the style hierarchy to resolve them for any given piece of text. There is no API support in `python-pptx` for this yet.

Comment: Managed to by pass this by looping over the paragraphs and then the runs of each and using run.font.italic... worked for me. Hope it is stable enough. Thank you Scanny!

Answer (score 0):

If the default font size, name, boldness, etc. was never changed then pptx returns None. You can change the attributes and then it should show the correct values.